# Apache Spark structured streaming word count example in local mode is super slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, latency, word-count

I'm trying to run Apache Spark word count example for structured streaming in local mode and I get a very high latency of 10-30 seconds. Here's the code I'm using (taken from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html):

```
host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", host) \
    .option("port", port) \
    .load()

words = lines.select(
   explode(
       split(lines.value, " ")
   ).alias("word")
)

# Generate running word count
wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

query = wordCounts \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

In the programming guide it's mentioned that the latency should be about 100 ms, and this doesn't seem a complicated example. Another thing to mention is that when I'm running this without any processing (just streaming the data to the output), I see the results immediately.

The example was ran on Ubuntu 18.04, Apache Spark 2.4.4.

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!
Gal